# Validation on a list using IF, AND and ISBLANK

Tags: validation

Im trying to validate my list in SharePoint 2010, so that it will only proceed when a column = xyz and a date column is not empty.

I took a stab at the syntax and came up with this.

```
=IF(AND([Status]='Closed',(NOT(ISBLANK([Actual Date of Acknowledgement])))
```

but it doesn't work.

Can somebody let me know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Where are you placing this validation?

Comment: its going in the Validation Settings, section which should cover the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing syntax...here's a sample formula for an IF with an AND statement. An IF statement needs to return something...you're not returning anything.

```
=IF(AND([Column1]>[Column2], [Column1]<[Column3]), "OK", "Not OK")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Column validation has an implicit "IF" already built in:

```
=AND([column a]="Test",(NOT(ISBLANK([column b]))))
```

will only let the item be saved if "column a"=Test AND "column b" is not empty.

So take the IF out and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The validation statement needs to evaluate to TRUE for your list item to save. Ditch the nested IF and just use AND:
=IF([Status]='Closed',AND([Actual Date of Acknowledgement]<>""),TRUE)

Hint 1: Research Excel AND function, and test it in Excel
Hint 2: Leave off the equals sign if it confuses you (as it does me). SharePoint will supply it for you.